# Visual Studio 2015 Project Templates (C++) won't create project file in specific location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, project

I'm trying to find how to create my own VC++ project template with all parameters set up for future development. But suddenly I appeared to stuck at a little problem: VS2015 won't create given structure inside of the project folder.

That's how my directory looks like inside of .zip file used for templating inside of Visual Studio:

```
Project/%ProjectName%.vcxproj

Project/%ProjectName%.vcxproj.filters

Project/%ProjectName%.vcxproj.user

Src/Main.cpp

MyTemplate.vstemplate
```

To be precise, it won't place .vcxproj file into the

> %created_project_folder%/Project

directory, but directly into

> %created_project_folder%/

directory instead, ruining file dependencies specified inside of project file. E.g. "include ../Src/Main.cpp" won't work because it will seek for file in wrong location.

I attached link to my .zip file below.

https://fex.net/#!654242360762

You can try to copy that onto @user@\Documents\Visual Studio XXXX\Templates\ProjectTemplates folder and then create project in VS. Project file will be created on the root instead of custom location.